# Mongo DB Backup and Restore

Tags: mongodb, backup

I'm new to using Mongo DB and was wondering if anyone could explain to me how to make reliable and accurate backups of my mongo data.

Comment: There are a few different options for you, have look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/

Answer (score 1):

Option A ( Online ):

1. For databases with storage size < 500GB you can use mongodump/mongorestore or ops manager(if you have it).
2. For bigger database sizes more effective is to do storage or lv snapshots from the backend file system , you can lock some members and do the snap and unlock it later, the snap takes few seconds, after you have the snapshots you can copy and keep safe somewhere.

Option B ( offline):

Offline backup -> You shutdown the instances and copy the data dir & configs to safe place.

P.S.
From replicaSet it is enought to keep single member snapshot.
From sharded cluster , single copy from 1x data member per shard + 1x CSRS copy.